# Mac OS X Mavericks: Applications not opening

Tags: macos, mac

```
My System Preferences:
27-inch, Mid 2011
Processor  2.7 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory  4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics  AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB
Serial Number  C02H2A7YDHJP
Software  OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
```

I have been having troubles opening any application other than preinstalled ones on my iMac.
Some applications are:

• Eclipse

• Skype

• ETC.

They arent opening please sugest anything that might help :)

They bounce forever but never open :(

I have tried doing Command + R on startup but I didnt know what to do from there, also I have tried to repair permissions but that didnt work either

Comment: Welcome to superuser! It would actually be quite helpful if you went into detail about the things you have tried so far.

Comment: @Twisty I have tried doing Command + R on startup but I didnt know what to do from there, also I have tried to repair permissions but that didnt work either

Comment: I put your additional info directly into your question, which is the preferred to adding it via comments.

Comment: Did you try to open the application from the Finder using right/double finger click and select "Open" from the dropdown menu? For downloaded applications, OSX requires to open it manually first  (only once per application) before an application can be launched normally (see: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14369).

Answer (score 0):

You may need software update for skype but OS X automatically moves incompatible software to a folder called Incompatible Software at the root level of your startup drive. See article at http://www.macworld.com/article/2055518/installing-mavericks-what-you-need-to-know.html